# How to hide API keys from client side when using Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure, backend, azure-keyvault

I have used Azure Key Vault to store some API keys, and I have a client-side application that can get the secrets from the Key Vault and use the API keys to connect to a server.

However, I don’t want to expose the API keys to the client side, because that would compromise their security.

How can I hide the API keys from the client side? Do I need to create an intermediate backend service?

Comment: Please provide a bit more clarity. If you hide the keys from the client how are you expecting it to use the API key to connect to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application calls Azure Key Vault, which returns the secret. At some point, the secret will appear unencrypted in the user's browser network log.

Depending on your use case, you may want to create a back-end service that does this for the user.